# ScrollTop offset Sticky Bar with multiple anchors

Tags: javascript, jquery, anchor, offset, scrolltop

I'm trying to build a sticky bar that fixes to the top after you pass the hero, and then after you pass each section on the page, the anchors in the sticky bar add/remove a class to show the active state of where they are on the page.

So basically as you scroll down the page, the sticky bar should move/animate left or right in the sticky nav depending on the sections they are passing on the page.

I have the sticky bar fixing to the top working correctly if I remove the other JS for the modules, but once I try to get everything working together, I can't seem to figure it out. I'm not very familiar with this level of javascript, so any help would be great!

Here is my jsfiddle: [jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/daysable/9qb1ea4u/17/)

```js
// hero
var p = $( ".hero" );
var offset = p.offset();
offset = offset.top;

$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop()   >  offset ) {
 $('.sticky-nav').addClass('fixed');
  $('li a.nav-1').addClass('active');
    }
  else { $('.sticky-nav').removeClass('fixed'); }
    $('li a.nav-1').removeClass('active');
});

// module 1
var p = $( ".module-1" );
var offset = p.offset();
offset = offset.top;

$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop()   >  offset ) {
 $('li a.nav-2').addClass('active');
    }
  else { $('li a.nav-2').removeClass('active'); }
});

// module 2
var p = $( ".module-2" );
var offset = p.offset();
offset = offset.top;

$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop()   >  offset ) {
 $('li a.nav-3').addClass('active');
    }
  else { $('li a.nav-3').removeClass('active'); }
});
// module 2
var p = $( ".module-3" );
var offset = p.offset();
offset = offset.top;

$(window).scroll(function () {  
    if ($(window).scrollTop()   >  offset ) {
 $('li a.nav-4').addClass('active');
    }
  else { $('li a.nav-4').removeClass('active'); }
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  max-width: 1440px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.hero {
  height: 200px;
  width: 1440px;
}
.sticky-nav {
  height: 70px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}
.module-1 {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%
}
.module-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 100%;
}
.module-3 {
  height: 400px;
  width: 100%;
}
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style-type: none;
}
li {
  width: 20%;
}
li a {
  color: #fff;
}
.active {
  border-bottom: 3px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="hero">I'm the hero</div>
<div class="sticky-nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#module-1" class="nav-1">nav a</a></li>
    <li><a href="#module-2" class="nav-2">nav b</a></li>
    <li><a href="#module-3" class="nav-3">nav c</a></li>
    <li><a href="#module-4" class="nav-4">nav d</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<a name="module-1"><section class="module-1">section 1</section></a>
<a name="module-2"><section class="module-2">section 2</section></a>
<a name="module-3"><section class="module-3">section 3</section></a>
<a name="module-4"><section class="module-4">section 4</section></a>
</div>
```

Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script have too many `$(window).scroll(function ()` .You can try it in a simpler way like below snippet.

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
 
  $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   $(document).off("scroll");
 
   $('a').each(function () {
    $(this).removeClass('active');
   })
   $(this).addClass('active');
 
   var target = this.hash;
   $target = $(target);
   $('html, body').stop().animate({
    'scrollTop': $target.offset().top+2
   }, 500, 'swing', function () {
    window.location.hash = target;
    $(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
   });
  });
 });
 
 function onScroll(event){
  var scrollPosition = $(document).scrollTop();
  var hero=$('.hero').innerHeight();
  (scrollPosition > hero)?$('header').addClass('sticky'):$('header').removeClass('sticky');
  $('nav a').each(function () {
   var currentLink = $(this);
   var refElement = $(currentLink.attr("href"));
   if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPosition && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPosition) {
    $('nav ul li a').removeClass("active");
    currentLink.addClass("active");
   }
   else{
    currentLink.removeClass("active");
   }
   });
 };
```

```css
html, body { margin: 0; padding: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%;}
header.sticky {
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 80px;
 background: #fff;
}
nav {
 width: 960px;
 height: 80px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
nav ul {
 margin: 20px 0 0;
}
nav ul li {
 display: inline-block;
 margin: 0 30px 0 0;
}

a { color: #4D4D4D;  font-family: sans-serif; text-transform: uppercase; text-decoration: none; line-height: 42px; }
.active { color: #2dbccb; }

.content { width: 100%; height: 100%; }
.content > section { width: 100%; height: 100%; }

#home { background: #2dbccb; }
#about { background: #f6c362; }
#services { background-color: #eb7e7f; }
#contact { background-color: #415c71; }
.hero {
 padding: 150px 0;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">
 hero
</div>
<header>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a class="active" href="#home">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
</header>
<div class="content">
    <section id="home"></section>
    <section id="about"></section>
    <section id="services"></section>
    <section id="contact"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: @Phillyday did u get the ans?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! works perfectly. Thank you for your help.